# How to get an IP address of a client?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to get an IP address of a client, this doesn't work:

```
  def create(conn) do
    ip_address = conn.inet.ip_address
    # ....
```

due to `key :inet not found in: %Plug.Conn`. How can I get an IP address then?

Answer (score 28):

The get the IP:

`conn.remote_ip`

Casting from ip_address to string:

`to_string(:inet_parse.ntoa(conn.remote_ip))`

Comment: The casting code is not Elixir :)
This is the Elixir way: `conn.remote_ip |> :inet_parse.ntoa |> to_string()` ;)

Answer (score 16):

Check this [Request fields](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#module-request-fields):

> remote_ip - the IP of the client, example: {151, 236, 219, 228}. This field is meant to be overwritten by plugs that understand e.g. the X-Forwarded-For header or HAProxy’s PROXY protocol. It defaults to peer’s IP.

This is what you're looking for:

```
conn.remote_ip
```

Comment: `conn.remote_ip |> Tuple.to_list |> Enum.join(".")` will work also. No need to do the `Integer.to_string` call.

Comment: The mentioned examples only work for IPv4 addresses. If you want a solution for IPv4 and IPv6, use the [ntoa](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#ntoa-1) function of Erlang's inet: `conn.remote_ip |> :inet.ntoa() |> to_string()`